# Two instances of OpenTelemetry running in the same app

Tags: java, open-telemetry

Wanted to ask your opinion: is it possible to have two separate instances of OpenTelemetry collecting different data  in one java application?

Unfortunately, I can`t test 2 instances, so asking maybe someone had such a problem:) thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to set up and use multiple `OpenTelemetry` instances in an app. The only thing that you have to be careful about is not setting the [`GlobalOpenTelemetry`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/latest/io/opentelemetry/api/GlobalOpenTelemetry.html) more than once (you can skip using it entirely).

Comment: Curious to know how this would be useful? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to have multiple exporters, but a single "OTel instance?

Comment: In general, I think it would be more appropriate to use multiple exporters.

I can imagine a use case where you'd want to instrument several different apps deployed on a single application server; in which case it'd make sense to me to set up separate OpenTelemetry instances (with separate Resource).

Comment: the situation is: we`re using corporate framework that has built in tracing functionality (based on OpenTracing - ancestor of OpenTelemetry). We developed another small tracing application for our department (we use OTEL). And now guys are moving from OpenTracing to OpenTelemetry, so we fear the side effects.

Comment: We have a shim/bridge library developed specifically for migrating OpenTracing users to OpenTelemetry: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/opentracing-shim/README.md - might be interesting to you.
Depending on how much of the framework you can control, you could perhaps inject the shim Tracer instead of the "real" OT tracer. If this is not possible, feel free to create 2 SDK instances. We do recommend merging them into one though, if there's no business case behind the multiple instances.

Comment: single application server; in which case it'd make sense to me to set up separate OpenTelemetry instances (with separate Resource)

But then it's still the same thing no? Each app configures its own OTel instance/resource and that's it. I don't see how them being hosted on the same app server influences anything on the number of "OTel instances configured".

Comment: > I don't see how them being hosted on the same app server influences anything on the number of "OTel instances configured". -- Correct, because it shouldn't, conceptually these are separate applications (even if they're running in the same JVM process).